# qt open excel name passing error

Tags: c++, excel, qt

now i am making one program which reads two excel sheets and makes it one.

and all are fine. but i have one problem

that is

```
    QAxWidget *excel=new QAxWidget("Excel.Application", this);
    excel->dynamicCall("SetVisible", true);
    QAxObject *workbooks=excel->querySubObject("WorkBooks");
    workbooks->dynamicCall("Open(const QString&)", QString(":/temp/temp.xls"));
    QAxObject *workbook=excel->querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook");
    QAxObject *worksheets=workbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets");
```

my qrc file

```
    <RCC>    
       <qresource prefix="/">        
          <file>temp/temp.xls</file>    
       </qresource>
    </RCC>
```

workbooks->dynamicCall("Open(const QString&)", QString(":/temp/temp.xls"));
this part occurs error

i inserted one excel template file into my resource.qrc

and i tried to open but it didn't work.

if i passed absolute path of the file, then work. but if i passed relative path of the file, don't work

how can i solve this??
please let me know..
thanks

Comment: How can you give relative path when you have it as resources ?

Comment: if i add an excel file to the qrc file, i can access this file :/temp/temp.xls but it is not working. and if i give c:\user\desktop\temp\temp.xls then it works

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put you excel file in some directory inside the project like docs or something.
2. Set your current directory QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath())
3. You can access the files inside doc folder like "docs/anyfile.xls"

If you put the xls file inside resources it will bundled inside executable and won't be accessible by Microsoft Office COM components.

Comment: thanks. i made like that. and when i am releasing this project to the install file. how to includes this template file?

Comment: Just copy the docs folder along with binary where executable exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put you excel file in some directory inside the project e.g. templates.
   So you structure will be

   `ProjectMainDirectory/
        + - MyResources.qrc
        + - template/
            + - temp.xls`
2. Add the file as a resource. The resource file will be like :

   `<RCC>
       <qresource prefix="/Files">
           <file>template/temp.xls</file>
       </qresource>
   </RCC>`
3. Now try and access the file as `":/Files/template/temp.xls`. You should be able to access the file.

When you compile the compiler will read the resource file and package the resource file in the exe itself. You will not need to package the xls file along with the exe separately.

Hope that solves the problem. If any problems please leave a comment.

Comment: thanks. it will be one more solution. but i heard about that if i add a file into the .qrc file, this file is only read only. but i want to open this file write only. if it is not, i will use your solution. reply plz

Comment: Yes as you mentioned it correctly files added in qrc are read only. This is because they are packaged into the exe itself. It would be more helpful if you state what exactly your problem is, What exactly do you want to achieve with the excel file ?

Comment: my program is reading the data from two excel sheet. and extracting data, write to the one excel sheet and save. and i want to write all extracted data to the template file and save. my client wants template excel sheet must be loaded automatically. and when i releasing this project, i have to release including this template